# Why the type of "testScores["dave"]" is "Optional<Array<Int>>.Type" instead of "<Array<Int>>.Type"

Tags: swift, subscript, dynamictype

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of subscript. When I tried to find out the returned value of testScores["dave"], I was expecting `Array<Int>.Type`, however, the IDE instead outputted `Optional<Array<Int>>.Type`.

Why this is the case? Am I missing something?

```
var testScores = ["dave": [82, 84, 86], "jen": [23, 14, 5], "ben": []]

testScores["dave"].dynamicType
```

Comment: dictionary values will always be optional. There is no guarantee that there will be a value set for any key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you get a value from a `Dictionary` it will be optional. It might or might not have an entry for the specified key. That is why you have to unwrap the optional before you can use it.